# Does there exist an O(n) algorithm for finding the smallest substring from an input string, containing a given character set and count?

Tags: c#, string, algorithm, time-complexity

Given a string `s`, and a set of characters with count, find the minimal substring in `s` that contains all the characters repeating their count number of times.

**Example:**

```
charcount = { { 'A', 3 }, { 'B', 1 } }; 
str = "kjhdfsbabasdadaaaaasdkaaajbajerhhayeom" 

---> "aajba"
```

I know how to do it in `O(n^2)` time by iterating through all the substrings from smallest to largest.

Possible signature of function:

```
string SmallestSubstringWithCharacterCount(Dictionary<char,int> chardic, string source)
{
   // ... 
}
```

I'm guessing there's some way where you can iterate through `str` because once you get to

```
"kjhdfsbabasdadaaaaasdkaaajbajerhhayeom" 
             |
           here
```

you're found the first string, `"kjhdfsbabasda"`, containing all the characters in the set.

Comment: Just curious, which algorithm do you use that would lead to `O(n^2)` ? If you pass a `List<Dictionary<char,int>> charListAndCount` and iterate it through single for/foreach you can get the results with `O(n)` + IMHO, a negligible time for looping through the list.

Comment: @uteist O(n^2) is going through all substrings. which is what I assume OP wants. I am unsure why you think your approach will find the required substring.

Comment: Though the O(n^2) solution is actually `O(n^3)`, there are `O(n^2)` substrings and iterating each of them is `O(n)`.

Comment: Ah, my bad, sry. Focused on "first" substring rather than "minimal"

Comment: Do you need **exactly** the counts or **at least**? E.g. with `{b: 2, a: 2}`, would `baaaaaab` be acceptable or not?

Comment: @Holt Yes, that would be acceptable. Needs to contain those characters in at least the amounts assigned to them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find smallest substring which contains all characters from a given string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459653/how-to-find-smallest-substring-which-contains-all-characters-from-a-given-string)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, linear algorithm does exist.

You need additional currentcharcount set with initial zero counts and GoodCount counter.

Make two index pointers - left and right, and move them through input string.

If next char is from the set, increment count for this char in currentcharcount.   If this count becomes equal to goal value, increment GoodCount.
Move right index until GoodCount reaches charcount length - now current substring contains all needed chars.

Then move left index, decrementing counts, and decrementing GoodCount when needed. Just before this step we have the shortest substring starting here.

After decrementing GoodCount -  repeat process with right index and so on to choose the best from all the shortest substrings.

Comment: What if the minimal substring is at the right end of the original string?

Comment: @Holt Then right index stops at the end, and left index walks to the beginning of minimal substring. Overall number of steps cannot cannot exceed 2*N

Comment: *"Move right index until GoodCount reaches charcount length"*, as I understand it, you stop moving as soon as you have an acceptable substring, so what if you have an acceptable substring at the beginning which is not the minimal? With your algorithm, I would expect to find `aajba` inside `aajbakaaba` instead of `aaba` which is the expected answer...

Comment: @Holt Cycle of right moving/left moving should been repeated to find the best solution. Made an edit to specify it.

Comment: After your edit, I see what you are doing. You also need to remember the minimal substring you have currently found each time GoodCount reach the correct value, I guess?

Comment: Yes, remember left and right indexes - but just before GoodCount decrementing